# Having a program remember a scheduler after exit

Tags: .net, windows, scheduled-tasks

I inherited a simple scheduler in a program that runs particle counters. I fixed the basic functions and it now works properly (schedule start/end times and counters turn off/on for those times).

Right now, I am using a single timer event that checks every second to compare scheduled tasks with current time to start/stop them. However, the current setup only remembers the latest schedule. I think I can fix this by building a list of schedules and loop through and check/compare their objects properties to determine starting/stopping.

What I am struggling to get down design wise is, if a person shuts down the program all schedules are lost. Should I use a database to store this information, then retrieve on startup of the application? Should I use a different approach and use an outside scheduler like Windows scheduler or Quartznet?

Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: How much data are we talking about?  If it's a relatively small amount of data that infrequently changes, use an XML file.  Otherwise, use a database like SQL Server Compact.

Comment: The people who want this functionality will probably only need to hold anywhere from 3 to 10 schedules of different devices. I can't imagine anyone would need more.